# Weird zooming in Premiere Pro preview-window

Tags: video, premiere, video-editor, adobe

After a hard time getting my Premiere Pro CC to work correctly,
I stumbled upon a new problem.

In the image below, you can see how the frame is about 200% zoomed in the preview window, and normal in the "source"-window. I've checked the magnification level, but it's ok. Resolution is set to "Full".

The preview was a square and zoomed at first, so I created a new sequence, but now it's widescreen and zoomed.

How do I make the preview normal again?

[image: Weird zooming]

Comment: Fixed it by creating a new project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the resolution in the sequence is the same as the resolution of your clip. Otherwise you'll need to scale the video to fit correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to read the text in the screenshot, but it appears that the scale drop-down in the two windows is different. The one of the left appears to say "1,3", and the one on the right appears to say "Full" (which is what you said). That may not be THE answer, but it's something I noticed.

Comment: For my understanding (and experience) it's just for the playback quality. It won't scale my video, but change it's quality.